# MySQL showing SQL Error: 1048 as a warning instead of error

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

When updating a not null column to a null value locally it will throw an error, but when running against an AWS RDS instance it will be ok and report a warning.

eg. Against AWS RDS:

```
2018-05-31 15:41:23,066 [][][localhost]  WARN org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:232 - SQL Warning Code: 1048, SQLState: null
2018-05-31 15:41:23,068 [][][localhost]  WARN org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:233 - Column 'xxxxx' cannot be null
```

And against my local:

```
2018-05-31 15:02:07,023 [][][localhost]  WARN org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:144 - SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
2018-05-31 15:02:07,024 [][][localhost] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:146 - Column 'xxxxx' cannot be null
2018-05-31 15:02:07,029 [][][localhost]  INFO org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl:208 - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2018-05-31 15:02:07,035 [][][localhost]  WARN net.sourceforge.stripes.exception.DefaultExceptionHandler:90 - Unhandled exception caught by the Stripes default exception handler.
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

From my reading the sql_mode property handles this but changing the value has no effect. Setting my local to the same values as remote does not reproduce the behavior:

```
show variables where Variable_name like '%sql_mode%';
'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
```

**What is the setting that allows my AWS RDS instance to show a warning when locally it is an error?**

Additional information:

- Column definition: `xxxxx` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL
- Storage engine: InnoDB
- Local Version: 5.6.33-log and 5.6.27 (observed the issue in two different areas)
- Remote Version: 5.6.39-log

Comment: What is the table definition for column xxxxx, what is the storage engine for the table (both servers), and what does `SELECT @@VERSION` return on each server?

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot I've updated the description with the additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can set the SQL_MODE to "IGNORE" i.e. not easy to do it.

Alternative you can use the "INSERT IGNORE" so that the ERROR/WARNING will be ignored as below:

```
mysql> insert into x values(null);
ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'id' cannot be null
mysql> insert ignore into x values(null);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.15 sec)

mysql> select * from x;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  0 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert ignore into x values(null);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.16 sec)

mysql> select * from x;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  0 |
|  0 |
+----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Why would one server throw only a warning even though `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` seems to be active on both?

Comment: I'm trying to understand what's happening not because I want to force a warning. This does not help me solve my issue.

Comment: I have a similar issue--> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51193965/sql-query-not-working-on-rds/51194142?noredirect=1#comment89370431_51194142