# SQL Query not working on RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

> Using MySQL 5.6.40

This is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `updated_tables` (
  `table_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (`table_name`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `table_name_UNIQUE` (`table_name` ASC))
  ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

This is the query (Generated by Sequalize):

```
INSERT INTO `updated_tables` (`table_name`,`updated_at`) VALUES ('workdamnit',NULL) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `table_name`=VALUES(`table_name`), `updated_at`=VALUES(`updated_at`);
```

Simplified form of the same query:

```
INSERT INTO `updated_tables` (`table_name`,`updated_at`) VALUES ('workdamnit',NULL)
```

And it produces the following entry in table:

table_name: **workdamnit**

updated_at: **2018-07-05 14:27:17.142494**

Now to the question.

> Using MySQL 5.6.39-log on AWS RDS

Gives this error:
**Error Code: 1048. Column 'updated_at' cannot be null**

Is it since the MySQL versions are a bit different, or it has to do something with RDS?

Comment: I believe the error Message is self explanatory. You are trying to insert NULL in a field which does not allow NULL values, This field is updated_at.

Comment: You have a duplicate INDEX. You don't need the  **UNIQUE_INDEX** 'table_name_UNIQUE' as the **PRIMARY KEY** is already a UNIQUE value and an INDEX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found the answer. The RDS instance has a strict mode turned on by default, so it was responding properly. While my local instance, and also an instance of MySQL on EC2, were not using the strict mode.

Answer (score 3):

During the creation of your table you have mentioned the following on your column: `updated_at`:

1. Do not allow `NULL`
2. If nothing is provided, use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)` as default.

Hence, It is giving the error when you are inserting NULL in your query.

So, If I understand what you are trying to do currectly, this should be your query:

```
INSERT INTO `updated_tables` (`table_name`) VALUES ('workdamnit')
```

instead of

```
INSERT INTO `updated_tables` (`table_name`,`updated_at`) VALUES ('workdamnit',NULL)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the answer. the insertion query is being generated by Sequalize, thats why it is complicated. Your query is correct. But the problem remains.

Comment: can you edit your question with your sequalize code?

Comment: you can pass the flag to sequalize, example: `Model.find({where: {foo: undefined}, treatUndefinedAsNull: false})` not sure if insert allows the flag.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to `INSERT NULL` on a field that does not allow it. Furthermore this field has a default value. so you can simply try:

```
INSERT INTO `updated_tables` (`table_name`) VALUES ('workdamnit') ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, please read my question again. There is a difference with behavior depending where I used it.

Comment: @VedranMaricevic. there is a big chance in first environment the row already exists so an update is executed instead of insert. In second enviroment the row does not exist, so an insert is trying to be executed and fails for the reason I describe